# how to attach a body to a rope and making it swing to another rope

Tags: box2d, physics, cocos2d-iphone, rope-physics

I've set some ropes (using cocos2d and box2d) and would like to attach a body to one rope in such a way that it can swing to another rope. I am not sure how to go about this. I read  [making and object swing from one rope to another](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23515/making-an-object-swing-from-one-rope-to-another) but it didn't seem to be of any help.